# How to check float in diapason in C++?

Tags: c++

Simple way for diapason (A, B)

```
if (A < X && X < B) ...
```

But it seems that +INF, .NAN also lay in the diapason

Comment: what is `A,B,X` ? all floats? how can you choose A and B to have INF inside?

Comment: Does _Diapason_ mean _Interval_?

Comment: All numbers are floats, diapason is interval

Comment: Actually I have a complex function that should return values from 0 to 1, but sometimes it returns -1.#IND

Comment: Did you mean (A < X && X < B)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your condition is not an interval (diapason). It is functionally equivalent to

```
X < std::min(A, B)
```

You only have an upper bound, no lower bound at all.

---

Exactly how NaN and +Inf behave, depends on the floating point representation, which is not specified by the C++ standard, but is cpu specific.

If we assume the commonly used IEEE-754, then neither X=+Inf, nor X=NaN can satisfy the condition for any values of A and B.

---

This is how you check that a floating point number is between a lower and an upper bound (but equal to neither):

```
X > low && X < high
```

or

```
low < X && X < high
```

Again, if we assume IEEE-754, then neither X=+Inf, nor X=NaN can satisfy this condition for any values of low and high. But, since IEEE-754 might not be guaranteed, the behaviour of such numbers is not specified. You might need to be explicit to support exotic hardware:

```
low < X && X < high && std::isfinite(X)
```

Comment: Some people also find `low < X && X < high` more readable (because it's more similar to how you would write it mathematically: `low < X < high`). Presumably OP just made a typo. But again a nice example of how naming things properly quickly shows that `low > X` doesn't make sense.

Comment: @Groo good point about possibly being a typo. I added clarification that in IEEE-754, the condition is satisfied by neither Inf+ nor NaN when the interval is written correctly.